# C# String to Byte[]

Tags: c#

I want to convert a string to byte and output it as byte array.

example: string: 3074 output: 0C02

```
    private static byte[] ConvertHexToBytes(string input)
    {
        var result = new byte[(input.Length + 1) / 2];
        var offset = 0;
        if (input.Length % 2 == 1)
        {
            result[0] = (byte)Convert.ToUInt32(input[0] + "", 16);
            offset = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            result[i + offset] = (byte)Convert.ToUInt32(input.Substring(i * 2 + offset, 2), 16);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static void SetValue(string input)
    {
        byte[] port = ConvertHexToBytes(input);
        byte[] port = new byte[] { byte.Parse("" + port[0]), byte.Parse("" + port[1]) };
    }
```

I am getting 3074 instead of the 0C02.

Just figured it out, here is my code

```
    private static void SetValue(string input)
    {
        byte[] port = BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(input));
        byte[] res= new byte[] { port[1], port[0] };
    }
```

Comment: this code wont compile as you defined port twice in function SetValue

Comment: just fixed it, my bad

Comment: If you figured out an answer then pls post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're working with `int`, not `string` ("I want to convert a *string* to byte...")

```
  int input = 3074; // 00 00 0C 02
```

And you want to trim *leading zeroes* and get `"0C02"` string; you can do it with a help of *Linq*:

```
  byte[] result = 
    (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
        ? BitConverter.GetBytes(input).Reverse() 
        : BitConverter.GetBytes(input))
    .SkipWhile(b => b == 0)
    .DefaultIfEmpty() // we don't want trim all in case of input == 0
    .ToArray();
```

Test:

```
  // "0C02" 
  Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(result.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));
```

Combining it all into the proposed method:

```
  private static void SetValue(string input) {
    byte[] res = 
      (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
         ? BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(input)).Reverse() 
         : BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(input)))
      .SkipWhile(b => b == 0)
      .DefaultIfEmpty() // we don't want trim all in case of input == 0
      .ToArray();

    // Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(res.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")))); 

    //TODO: relevant code here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution which will work independent of the endianess of your system architecture which will make things more portable:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(input);

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
       Array.Reverse(bytes);
 Console.WriteLine("byte array: " + 
      BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty));
```